# custom attr errors when trying to use NLog on Mono on openSUSE

Tags: linux, mono, nlog, suse

I'm researching how much of the solution I have for Windows can be simply transplanted to Linux. Most of my actual program can operate, but our favourite logging module on Windows is NLog.

I'm having a problem on openSuse. When NLog starts (i.e. valid configuration is found), the program fails with several errors of the form:

```
Can't find custom attr constructor image: /share/MonoSIMON/MonoTestConsumer/NLog.dll mtoken: 0x0a000358
```

The error appears 9 times with NLog 3.2.0.0.

Initially I was running with a newer NLog V4.3.1.0, and the result is the same although there are around 15 copies of the error instead.

I'm not compiling Mono or anything, it's all as standard packages. I'm targeting Framework 4.5, it's a Console App, and I'm really not doing anything special.

Is it possible to run with NLog on openSuse.

Thanks for any help.

Mark

Comment: See this related issue,  it was missing a package: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/905

Comment: I have read that page, but I can't find an alternative openSuse package called libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil. I'm not too hot at Linux, how would I fetch the package using zypper if it's not in default repos?

Comment: I think it will be useful for future readers if you add the version of OpenSUSE you were using, and the version of Mono that this distro version provides

Answer (score 1):

I eventually worked this out. Julian pointed me back in the direction of the NLog issues board, but that package name doesn't work on openSuse 42.1.

A search on www.rpmfind.net shows that the system.service model assembly is actually in the openSuse 'mono-wcf' package.

```
zypper install mono-wcf
```

Fixes the NLog problem.

Cheers.

Comment: NLog shouldn't depend on WCF to run, so this is clearly a packaging bug in opensuse, please report the bug to OpenSUSE's bugzilla, saying something like "ServiceModel dll shouldn't be provided by wcf package, but by some libmono-system-servicemodel package, because logging facilities such as NLog should not depend on WCF to work"

Comment: To be fair, "ServiceModel" does sound like a WCF kind of thing. I'm not sure that it's a packaging fault, so I'm not going to bother OpenSuse issue board with it.